# How to use paste0 on both sides of an assignment operator within a loop across a sequence of numbers?

Tags: r

I have a character vector that contains the names of different cities.

```
names <- c("Tokyo","Bangkok")
```

I would like to store each city name in a separate character vector, which I could do by:

```
name_1 <- names[1]
name_2 <- names[2]
```

However, I would rather like to use a loop, which I tried by:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  paste0("name_",i) <- paste0("names[",i,"]")
}
```

This gives me an error message:

```
Error in paste0("name_", i) <- paste0("names[", i, "]") : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

How can I solve this problem? In my real data, I have hundreds of city names, which is why I want to use a loop or any other technique that saves me from writing a new line of code for every city name.

Comment: "I would like to store each city name in a separate character vector" — this question crops up all the time, and it is almost never the correct thing to do. *Keep your data in vectors!* Whenever you find yourself using numbered variable names, you are making your code more complex for no reason. The issue you are experiencing is a symptom of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`paste0` is a red herring here; it's not needed on the RHS. The function `assign` allows assignment to a variable as a character string:

```r
for (i in 1:2) {
  assign(paste0("name_", i), names[i])
}
```

This is not in general recommended. In this particular case, one can refer to the same value simply by `names[i]` as opposed to `names_i`, but your use-case may be different.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from a loop, you can also convert the vecter to a named list and then `list2env()`.

```r
names <- c("Tokyo", "Bangkok")

list2env(setNames(as.list(names), paste0("name_", seq_along(names))), .GlobalEnv)

name_1
# [1] "Tokyo"

name_2
# [1] "Bangkok"
```