# How to loop through names of character vectors?

Tags: r

I have two character vectors which include different city names.

```
names <- c("Tokyo","Bangkok")

for (i in 1:2) {
  assign(paste0("name_", i), names[i])
}
```

Based on these two character vectors, I would like to store the city names in a list, which I could do by:

```
names_list <- list(name_1, 
                   name_2)
```

However, I would rather like to use a loop, which I tried by:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  names_list <- list(paste0("name_", i))
}
```

However, as you can see, this does not give the desired outcome.

How can I solve this problem?

By the way, this is a follow up question to an earlier problem:

[How to use paste0 on both sides of an assignment operator within a loop across a sequence of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76411601/how-to-use-paste0-on-both-sides-of-an-assignment-operator-within-a-loop-across-a/76411625#76411625)

Comment: Couldn't `as.list(names)` be used?

Comment: Moreover, GKi's solution (or just: `list(names)` avoids unnecessarily cramming your workspace with junk assignments. You might also prefer object identifiers which are not yet occupied by existing R functions (like "names" vs. `names()`).

Comment: As an intermediary solution, you can also do `mget(ls(pattern = "name_"))` after the first for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```r
# data
names <- c("Tokyo","Bangkok")

# initialise list
nm_ls <- vector("list")

#loop
for (i in 1:2) {
  nm_ls[[paste0("name_", i)]] <-  names[i]
}
#result
nm_ls
#> $name_1
#> [1] "Tokyo"
#> 
#> $name_2
#> [1] "Bangkok"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-07 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. This is perfect. This does exactly what I need.

Comment: No problems, although I think @bension23's approach for initialising a list is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

First create an empty list, then `get` the vectors and append to the list using index `[`.

```r
name_1
#> [1] "Tokyo"
name_2
#> [1] "Bangkok"

names_list <- list()

for (i in 1:2) {
  names_list[i] <- get(paste0("name_", i))
}

names_list
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "Tokyo"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "Bangkok"
```